# Duvidas sobre requests e returns

Tags: laravel-5

Tenho 2 páginas diferente porém que acessam o mesmo controle. A ideia é que eu recupere qual página fez a requisição, pois dependendo qual for preciso da dois retornos diferentes.

Ex.

Tenho um botão para enviar um produto para o carrinho, porém este botão um está na `index` (página principal) e o outro está na descrição do produto. Caso eu clique no botão da `index`, ele deve me redirecionar para própria `index` porém incrementando o item ao carrinho, ja se eu estiver no detalhes do produto ele deve me redirecionar para detalhes do produto.

1. O `Laravel` facilita estes tipos de requisições, onde várias páginas acessam o mesmo `controller` e o `request` deve ser efetuado para página que fez a requisição como no exemplo acima ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade é um conjunto de fatores a principio as rotas que são configuradas com o tipo de [`verb`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) (`POST`, `GET`, `DELETE`, `PUT`), ***exemplo***:

```
Route::get('/exemplo', "ExemploController@index");
Route::post('/exemplo', "ExemploController@index");
```

isso significa que o endereço `/exemplo` aceita requisições configuradas no arquivo de rotas os [`verb`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) `POST` e `GET` e no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) pela [`classe` `Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) eu consigo definir vários comportamentos dentro de um ação (`Action`) do `controller`, ***exemplo***:

```
class ExemploController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //dependendo do verb eu faço determinada operação.
        if ($request->isMethod('get'))
        {
            return view('empresafuncao');
        }
        if ($request->isMethod('post'))
        { 
            return 'post';
        }
    }
}
```

> O [Laravel](https://www.laravel.com) pode trabalhar dessa forma?

***R.*** **Pode**, *mas, eu não recomendaria, por vários motivos, um deles e a quantidade de código que resolve diversos problemas quebrando uma regra da **Orientação a Objeto** que é responsabilidade única, onde um parte resolve um determinado problema, no caso **exemplo** apresentado, já está resolvendo dois, e pode até ficar pior se esse código tiver que ser alterado e crescer. A manutenção com isso se torna difícil e critica em diversos momentos da codificação.*

---

> O [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) facilita estes tipos de requisições, onde várias páginas acessam o mesmo `controller` e o `request` deve ser efetuado para página que fez a requisição como no exemplo acima?

**R.** **Sim**, *é bem fácil trabalhar com requisições e em conjunto com as rotas tirar proveitos e vários momentos, a relação do [`request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) é aquilo, **pode fazer a requisição para a mesma página**, mas, não é recomendável como já foi explicado nessa resposta.*

*O ideal, é que cada requisição tenha a sua `Action/Controller` e seu tipo de requisição associado ([`verb`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5)), onde o processo seja bem claro para resolver um determinado problema.*